# Create dynamic value from XML response

Tags: paw-app

I got a XML response from the service:

```
<token>80e7a83101cfd4f73920c7b4fdbe7f096fa9499c</token>
```

which is used in following POST requests as a Body param:

```
token=80e7a83101cfd4f73920c7b4fdbe7f096fa9499c
```

Is there a way how to create a dynamic value from the token? I need to copy-paste it manually every time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. Request Parsed Dynamic Values are working with JSON, XML and Form URL-Encoded bodies. Some docs is available here (though it's for JSON, and XML is not as well integrated in the UI): https://paw.cloud/docs/advanced/reuse-values-from-previous-responses

Here are some detailed steps for XML:

Right-click on a field, and pick: Response > Response Parsed Body

[image]

Enter the XML path to the object you want to access:

[image]

Unfortunately the XML path library we're currently using isn't always consistent, so to access text nodes, try `.text` or `.text[0]`…

In this example, I access the path `slideshow.slide.title.text[0]` this XML: https://httpbin.org/xml

Comment: Just got my Aha moment. Thx!

Comment: @Dave you mean partial XML trees? It's possible that the XML parser we're using fails if it's not a complete XML document.